# How to custom react-select set searching filter

Tags: react-select

```js
const ItemOptions: SelectValueInterface[] = Item.map((e) => ({
  value: e.ItemId,
  label: `${e.ItemName} (Item ID : ${e.ItemId})`,
}));
const options = [
  {
    label: 'ITEM NAME (Item ID)',
    options: ItemOptions,
  },
];

const formatGroupLabel = (data: any) => (
  <div className={styles.formatGroupLabel}>
    <span>{data.label}</span>
  </div>
);

<Select
  placeholder="Select Name"
  options={options}
  formatGroupLabel={formatGroupLabel}
  classNamePrefix="select-list"
  value={ItemOptions.filter((option) => option.value === selectedItemId)}
  onChange={filterByItemID}
/>;
```

When typing on searching/sorting, when I type `Item ID`, it shows all options. I would like to not detect `(Item ID: number)`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I customized my DropDown filter using this prop - `filterOption={customFilter}`:

```js
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import DropDownOptions from "./DropDownOptions";
import DropDownValueContainer from "./DropDownValueContainer";
import "./DropDown.less";

const DropDown = () => {
  const options = [
    { value: "value1", label: "Header1" },
    { value: "value2", label: "Header2" },
    { value: "value3", label: "Header3" },
  ];
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState({});
  const handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    setSelectedValue(selectedOption);
  };

  const colourStyles = {
    valueContainer: (base, state) => ({
      ...base,
      backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? "red" : "white",
    }),
    input: (base, state) => ({
      ...base,
      display: state.selectProps.menuIsOpen ? "block" : "none,"
    })
  };

  //Add your search logic here.
  const customFilter = (option, searchText) => {
    if (
      option.data.label.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
      option.data.value.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
    ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  return (
    <Select
      placeholder="Select Value"
      options={options}
      defaultValue={options[0]}
      onChange={handleChange}
      components={{
        Option: DropDownOptions,
        ValueContainer: DropDownValueContainer,
      }}
      isSearchable={true}
      styles={colourStyles}
      filterOption={customFilter}
      classNamePrefix="dropdownStyles"
    />
  );
};

export default DropDown;
```

[Go through this post to unserstand the code](https://medium.com/@lahiru0561/react-select-with-custom-label-and-custom-search-122bfe06b6d7)

Answer (score 3):

You can, by providing a [filterOption](https://react-select.com/advanced#custom-filter-logic) prop. The method you provide takes two arguments: `input`, which is the search, and `candidate`, an object of `{label, value, data}`. The `label` matches the return of your `getOptionLabel` (if you used a key other than `label`). The `value` matches the return of your `getOptionValue` (if you used a key other than `value`). The `data` is the full 'option' object you provided in your `options`.

```js
// a filter function that runs against each 'option' in `options`
const customFilter = useCallback((candidate, input) => {
  if (input) {
    // return true for each option that matches your filter
  }
  return true; // if not search, then all match
}, []);
// ...
<Select filterOption={customFilter} ...
```

Comment: `data` attribute was quite useful, thanks for the note.